# Can't get my loop & match to append to correct list

Tags: python

I´m experiencing problems with my code. 
I can´t get it to append to the list not_found as well as it loops twice for some reason.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? The match works for my_track, but it doesn't when it doesn't match.

```
# coding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python
import spotimeta
import sys
import time

my_tracks = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ").title().split()
playlist = []
real_playlist = []
not_found = []

def check_track(track_name, my_track, track_href):
    if track_name == my_track:
        playlist.append(track_href)
        return 1

# make sure the user does not input a single word as input
if (len(my_tracks) > 1):
    path = my_tracks[1]
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid input, please enter a sentence.")


# let's search
for my_track in my_tracks:
    match = 0
    print "Searching for '%s'\n" % (my_track),
    data = spotimeta.search_track(my_track)
    for result in data['result']:
        if not match == 1:
            try:
                match = check_track(result["name"],my_track,result["href"])
            except Exception, e:
                error = "not available"
            else:
                if data['total_results'] > 0:
                    not_found.append(my_track)
```

Comment: The hashbang (`#!`) is useless if it's not in the first line.

Comment: Please explain your problem more specifically. What is the expected output/behavior? What is the output/behavior you are getting instead? Also, please try to reduce your code-example by leaving out everything that is not required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Input: songname songname songname
Output: spotify urls to the matched song

Comment: Nowhere does this code attempt to append to `not_found`

Comment: if the track title has a space in it, isn't that going to screw things up?

Comment: In theory yes, but the output should be based on each word, i.e. "party girl" is splitted to party & girl.

Comment: why do you expect `check_track` to raise an exception?

Comment: Can´t get the else to work if it´s not there.. :/

Comment: What's the exception that raises?

Answer (score 0):

You should try debugging it.  One of the simplest ways of debugging is add the lines:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Then when you run the script it will stop at the `set_trace` line in the debugger.
Check out http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you're trying to do something like:

```
for my_track in my_tracks:
    print "Searching for '%s'\n" % (my_track),
    data = spotimeta.search_track(my_track)
    for result in data['result']:
        if result['name'] == my_track:
            playlist.append(result['href'])
        elif data['total_results'] > 0:
            not_found.append(my_track)
```

Will this more or less work for you?
Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I'm noticing two things.

First, you're checking `data['total_results']` a bit late; if the total results value is greater than zero (wait, what?), then you want to add it to the list immediately and move on without parsing the data.  I would, after the call from `spotimeta.search_track()`, check to see if this is the data you don't want (then subsequently add it into the list).

Second, I'm confused about the intention of your `for` loop.  If you're going through it to only find *one* item, then you can use the `in` statement (`my_track in result`).